# DirectSoundEnumerate() doesn't list driver name on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, device-driver, directsound

I have a program that is compiled on Windows XP and now I'm trying to run it on Windows 7 (both x86 and x64). The program uses DirectSound8 to enumerate all sound devices on the machine. The problem is that the enumerate function `DirectSoundEnumerate(...)` returns different results for **driver name** on Windows XP and Windows 7.

```
Windows XP
Device GUID =
Device description = Primary Sound Driver
Driver name =

Device GUID = {bd6dd71a-3deb-11d1-b171-00c04fc20000}
Device description = SigmaTel Audio
Driver name = sthda.sys

Windows 7 x86
Device GUID =
Device description = Primary Sound Driver
Driver name =

Device GUID = {4a1bd997-3986-4b7a-af02-7143e86af46c}
Device description = Speakers / Headphones (SigmaTel High Definition Audio CODEC)
Driver name = {0.0.0.00000000}.{4a1bd997-3986-4b7a-af02-7143e86af46c}

Windows 7 x64
Device GUID =
Device description = Primary Sound Driver
Driver name =

Device GUID = {aaee894b-7a80-44ff-805c-8d5e12207136}
Device description = Speakers / Headphones (SigmaTel High Definition Audio CODEC (for 64-bit Windows))
Driver name = {0.0.0.00000000}.{aaee894b-7a80-44ff-805c-8d5e12207136}
```

The three machine listed above have the same configuration of Dell Precision 390.

The program link to "DSound.lib" from DX9SDK_DEC2005.

Does anyone know why Windows 7 returns driver name as a GUID instead of the driver name?

Comment: I suppose you mean the **module name**. What do you need that for? To identify the device you'd best use the GUID.

Comment: Yes, I mean the module name (have seen both as argument name). The program uses module name and device description to match a speaker device to a microphone device (headphones). I have recompiled the code and removed the match with module name (only match device description) and then it works. But, the question still remains.

Comment: I'd answer your question as "it just is", although this might not be a satisfying answer. After all, DirectX is being discontinued anyways, at least for .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "driver name" you're seeing is the endpoint ID for the audio endpoint associated with the DSound device.  In general you shouldn't ever present this string to a customer, instead use the device description.

Comment: I found this in MSDN. It is as you say.
[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370837(VS.85).aspx)

"During DirectSound device enumeration, DirectSound supplies the endpoint ID string for each device that it enumerates."